# nuxt sitemap axios production

Tags: nuxt.js, sitemap, production

I am using Nuxt 2.15.3.

When I check the sitemap on the development environment everything works but in production the sitemap-structures does not work.

The problem is with the axios query but I can't find the problem.

Can you tell me the problem please?

```js
export default {
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL || "https://api.website.fr"
  },
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap"
  ],
sitemap: {
  hostname: process.env.BASE_URL || "https://website.fr",
  path: "/sitemap.xml",
  sitemaps: [
    {
      path: "/sitemap-pages.xml",
      routes: []
    },
    {
      path: "/sitemap-structures.xml",
      routes: async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.API_BASE_URL ||
            "https://api.website.fr"}/sitemap-routes`
        );

        return data.map(alias => `/alias/${alias}`);
      },
      exclude: ["/**"]
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Did you set `API_BASE_URL` env on production? Where do you host it? How do you build your application there? Tried to `console.log` your `return data.map` line both on dev and production?

Comment: Thank you.
I defined the base url in nuxt.config.js (see post).
i tried to put the full url but it doesn't work.
I run my application with npm run build then npm start.
I do not see the logs because it is on the server side.

Comment: I put the debug, I have the following error:
connect ECONNREFUSED IP ADDRESS

Comment: You can see project's logs during the build (any platform allows you to do so). Where is it hosted btw? You're using `target: server` I guess hence `npm run build`.

Comment: I am using target: server (for ssr)
my application is on a debian 10 server (I also have a reverse proxy I don't know if it's important).
I have the following error: 
 ERROR  connect ECONNREFUSED IP ADDRESS:443                                                                             09:53:13
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)

Comment: Looks like it's some kind of firewall issue here. Try looking for your rules and whitelist can is required here. Port 80 + 443 should be the cause.

Comment: When using a (local) server-side API. Should you use the ip or the url?

Comment: Having something like `localhost:1234` or `192.168.1.12:1234` is the way to go in those cases. No need to reach for the WAN, stay on LAN. Even if the hardware is capable to understand that and fix it for your, rather make it clean from the start.

Comment: and it must be in https or not ?

Comment: If it's on the same network, it's not critical. It will ask more work of course but it is **recommended** to have all your stuff in `https` nowadays (better google scoring, security, no huge drawbacks, no ugly warnings).

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the dotenv package so that the env variables can be accessed in the build mode

[npm dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: You don't need it, it is already included.